# Unicode displayed incorrectly

Tags: fonts, unicode, input-method, tex

I recently discovered `set-input-method TeX` and really like it!  But I noticed that certain characters are displayed incorrectly.  For example, `ₘ` is displayed as a superscript ⊕ to me: [image: wrong char]

To reproduce:

1. start emacs `emacs -q`
2. start buffer `C-x b foo`
3. copy-paste `ₘ` into emacs (alternatively: set input method to `TeX` and type `_m`)

Can somebody reproduce this error?  I am using emacs installed via snap on ubuntu 22.04:

```
xyz@asdf:~$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 29.1
Development version 28fb02492c24 on master branch; build date 2023-09-23.
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

If this isn't just an oddity of my system, does anybody know what may be causing it?

Here is the `C-u C-x =` info on the symbol:

```
             position: 10322 of 11224 (92%), column: 0
            character: ₘ (displayed as ₘ) (codepoint 8344, #o20230, #x2098)
              charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2098
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R
             to input: type "_m" with TeX input method
          buffer code: #xE2 #x82 #x98
            file code: #xE2 #x82 #x98 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-PfEd-Linux Libertine Display O-regular-normal-normal-*-34-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x644)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER M
  general-category: Lm (Letter, Modifier)
  decomposition: (sub 109) (sub 'm')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
  isearch-open-invisible org-fold-core--isearch-show
  isearch-open-invisible-temporary org-fold-core--isearch-show-temporary
  line-prefix          [Show]
  wrap-prefix          [Show]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it (I use Liberation Mono Regular).

Comment: @NickD I've done some experimenting, and so far all "regular" fonts render the symbol incorrectly (tested: Liberation Mono, Ubuntu Mono, Jetbrains Mono) while all "narrow/thin", "bold" or "italic" versions render it correctly. :-/  This is emacs only, gedit has no such problems.

Comment: What do you get if you do `C-u C-x =` on the symbol? Please update the question and add this information.

Comment: Added the `C-u C-x =` data, which looks inconspicuous to me (except that the symbol is still rendered incorrectly).

Comment: In my case, I get the correct display and `C-u C-x =` reports the same thing except for the font: `display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-GOOG-Noto Sans Mono-regular-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#xA13)`. Does your Help Screen show the subscript `m` or does it show the direct sum symbol?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same as you, but AFAICS it's just the font that I (and maybe you) are using.  Try a different font.

n.b. The following appears (to me) to be 'fixed' in my web browser, because my web browser is rendering this in a different font to Emacs.

`M-x describe-char` tells me:

```
            character: ₘ (displayed as ₘ) (codepoint 8344, #o20230, #x2098)
              charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2098
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 2098" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER M"
          buffer code: #xE2 #x82 #x98
            file code: #xE2 #x82 #x98 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-PfEd-Linux Libertine Display O-regular-normal-normal-*-61-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x644)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER M
  general-category: Lm (Letter, Modifier)
  decomposition: (sub 109) (sub 'm')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing our it was a font issue.  I've done some experimenting, and so far all "regular" fonts render the symbol incorrectly (tested: Liberation Mono, Ubuntu Mono, Jetbrains Mono) while all "narrow/thin", "bold" or "italic" versions render it correctly.  This is emacs only, gedit or the terminal has no such problems.

Comment: It's not so much what regular font you use as it is what font substitution Emacs makes when your regular font does not contain the symbol. E.g. in my case I use `Liberation Mono Regular`, but the subscripted `m` is displayed by `Google Noto Sans Mono` instead (and displayed correctly). In your case (and @phils' case above), you seem to use `-PfEd-Linux Libertine Display O` and that seems to cause the problem. But I'm no font expert, so I wouldn't be able to tell you how to use the Noto Sans font e.g. nor am I able to tell you why I end up using it: AFAICT, it's how my Emacs (`-Q`) works.